# ByteBuffer Performance

Tags: java, regex, nio, bytebuffer, nio2

I have a socket which will be receiving more than 1000 TPS, so I need the reading to be as fast as possible, in this socket I read the info and I need to build and String and check if it matches a regex. I need to read char by char, so I can now where a new message is sent

But I'm having perfomance issues, I'm testing it with JMeter and after some time the throughput start going down. SO far this is the best way I find to read the elements and classify them (chat by char), because the only way I know when a message new message starts/ends is because the NULL, The code below

```
//Keep reading info from the socket    
while (running) {
    try {
        Future<Integer> readFuture = getWorker().read(buffer);
        Integer option = readFuture.get();
        if (option > 0) {
            buffer.flip();
            //Read all the info from the buffer
            while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                char buf = (char) buffer.get();
                if (buf == '/') {
                    continue;
                }
                //If the info has one of those char, it's a new message, so I have to manage and keep reading
                if (buf == '\0' || buf == ' ') {
                    trace=sendMessage(trace);
                } else {
                    trace.append(buf);
                }
            }
            buffer.clear();
        } else {
            trace=sendMessage(trace);
            running = false;
            close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Error management 
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are having performance issues with *correctly working code*, you should consider asking this question on code review.  According to their [help page](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), question are on-topic there "If you are looking for feedback on a specific working piece of code from your project in the following areas…

* Best practices and design pattern usage
* Security issues
* **Performance**
* Correctness in unanticipated cases"

Comment: But if performance is a problem, relying on null-terminated strings in your protocol is probably a bad idea.

Comment: The thing with the null-terminated strings is that is an external system, so I can't control that, the will be sending huge amount of data over the socket, but I need to get every message, and each message has a different lenght.

Comment: @user1623801 That's a shame. Oh well, if you can't change the format, and the throughput seems fine initially, I'd look at two things: any bottlenecks or waiting queue build-ups in the executor service that processes the data and GC.

Comment: that was my first thought, so I removed the invocation of the executor where the message is processed and the time was the same, I've tried with differente buffer sizes, but I think that the buffer.hasRemaining() is decreasing the throughput, because there are two whiles the first one which keeps reading from the socket, the one who read all the info from the buffer

Comment: You should be able to do 100 TPS using just about any approach you can think of.  100 per second is 10 ms each or about 30,000,000 clock cycles if you use just one thread. I suggest you start with a very simple Socket with a dedicated thread with an InputStream and you should be able to handle at least 30,000 per second.

Comment: For simplicity I would send newline terminated text.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of not the fastest but the simplest code you could possibly write to send chat messages.  You can use NIO, and in fact I do but only when I really need to.

This example just uses new line terminated text.  For binary I would suggest writing the size of each message as a 32-bit value before each message. (possibly 16-bit if you know they are always small)

[Server side code](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Performance-Examples/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/tcp/TextEchoServerMain.java) and the [Client side code](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Performance-Examples/blob/master/src/main/java/vanilla/java/tcp/TextEchoClientMain.java)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
    while (true) {
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("Accepted " + s);
            try {
                try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                     PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8), true)) {
                    for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; )
                        handle(line, pw);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                System.out.println("... " + s + " closed");
            }
        }).start();
    }
}

static void handle(String line, PrintWriter pw) {
    pw.println(line);
}
```

These print the results

```
 Throughput test wrote 44.2 MB/s
 Latency test for 100,000 TPS
 Latency distribution 50/90 99/99.9 (worst) was 528,477/1,069,998 1,163,770/1,173,065 (1,174,106) micro-seconds
 Latency test for 80,000 TPS
 Latency distribution 50/90 99/99.9 (worst) was 276,228/498,628 551,875/556,160 (556,636) micro-seconds
 Latency test for 60,000 TPS
 Latency distribution 50/90 99/99.9 (worst) was 14/22 1,759/3,031 (3,393) micro-seconds
 Latency test for 50,000 TPS
 Latency distribution 50/90 99/99.9 (worst) was 14/21 4,388/5,518 (5,641) micro-seconds
 Latency test for 40,000 TPS
 Latency distribution 50/90 99/99.9 (worst) was 14/15 22/485 (2,071) micro-seconds
 Latency test for 30,000 TPS
 Latency distribution 50/90 99/99.9 (worst) was 14/15 21/921 (3,360) micro-seconds
 Latency test for 20,000 TPS
 Latency distribution 50/90 99/99.9 (worst) was 15/19 24/46 (656) micro-seconds
```

From this I can conclude that one thread can't handle even 80,000 short messages per second but it can handle 60,000 per second reasonable well and you get more stable results at 40,000 per second.

These get good results *because they have a very high TPS* and in fact at 100 TPS or less you see a side effect of *low message rates*  This side effect is due to the CPU caches getting disturbed every 10 ms due to the timer interupt and other interrupts and this hurts latency not on the 1 in 100 or so in these examples, but rather on every single message.

In short, you have to optimize <100 TPS differently because the message rate is **so low**, not because this is so high.

Comment: Hey peter, sorry I made a mistake, it is 10000 TPS, so necessaraly the information must have a new line, I have a question, is there is way I got wron messages, I mean, each message has a half from one and a part from the next one? I say it because I dont have countrol on the client side since it's an external system

How did you get this data of the TPS?

Comment: @Alex when you get a blocking read, you are only guaranteed to get 1 byte. This can mean you can get part of a message, or the end of one message and the start of another or multiple messages from a single read. If you can't control the client side you can't control the rate either. I suggest you create a test client which you can control to measure the TPS. BTW 10,000 TPS should be a problem even using plain old IO.  When NIO really helps is when you get above 40K TPS per thread.

Comment: @Alex I mean 10,000 TPS shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Lawrey, I'm going to test it using plain old IO, but now I have a new question, usin NIO2 is the same thing? I mean reading line by line? Because I've only seen it allows to use ByteBuffers

Comment: @Alex NIO2 is like NIO except twice as complicated and marginally slower unless you have specialist hardware like Infini-band which provides direct support.

Comment: You said, it can't handle 80K TPS, but the time was 556,636 micro seconds, that like half second, what I understood is it can't handle 100K

Comment: @Alex You are right though 100K also works provided you have no expectations as to what the latency profile should look like. 80K is the point at which the typical latencies increase by ~20,000x for only a 33% increase in TPS.